# Call multiple attributes from one class into another - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

I'm working with multiple classes that share some initial common variables/attributes. In order to make it *cleaner* and avoid calling the same variables multiple times I want to set them all in an initial class (e.g. `classA`) and then load all this attributes in a `classB`.

So I would define:

```
class classA:
   def __init__(self, varA, varB, varC, ..., varZ):
      self.varA = varA
      self.varB = varB
      self.varC = varC
      (...)
      self.varZ = varZ
```

And then load it in a second `classB`

```
class classB:
   def __init__(self, classA):
      self.varA = classA.varA
      self.varB = classA.varB
      self.varC = classA.varC
      (...)
      self.varZ = classA.varZ
```

Is there a better way to make this happen, without going over all the individual attributes?

Comment: `class classB(classA)`?

Comment: If `classB` is fully derived from `classA`, you could inherit `B` from `A` like Rakesh suggests. If it shares only some attributes, you could have a common base class `classCommon` and have both `classA` and `classB` inherit from that one

Comment: I may be wrong, but from my understanding by just inheriting I would have to input all the variables again when calling  `classB`, instead of just calling `classB(classA)` in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and inheritance:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


data = {'varA': 'a', 'varB': 'b', 'varC': 'c'}
a = A(**data)
b = B(**data)

print(a.varB == b.varB)
```

Out:

```
True
```